# in plutus-pioneer-program iteration 3 not able to use --required-signer-hash in grab.sh so causing beneficiary's signature missing error (if remove)

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, blockchain, cardano-address

Invalid option `--required-signer-hash'

Usage: cardano-cli transaction build
[ --byron-era
| --shelley-era
| --allegra-era
| --mary-era
| --alonzo-era
]
[ --shelley-mode
| --byron-mode [--epoch-slots NATURAL]
| --cardano-mode [--epoch-slots NATURAL]
]
(--mainnet | --testnet-magic NATURAL)
[--script-valid | --script-invalid]
[--witness-override WORD]
(--tx-in TX-IN
[--tx-in-script-file FILE
[(--tx-in-datum-file FILE | --tx-in-datum-value JSON VALUE)
( --tx-in-redeemer-file FILE
| --tx-in-redeemer-value JSON VALUE
)]])
[--required-signer FILE]
[--tx-in-collateral TX-IN]
[--tx-out ADDRESS VALUE
[ --tx-out-datum-hash HASH
| --tx-out-datum-hash-file FILE
| --tx-out-datum-hash-value JSON VALUE
| --tx-out-datum-embed-file FILE
| --tx-out-datum-embed-value JSON VALUE
]]
--change-address ADDRESS
[--mint VALUE
(--mint-script-file FILE
[--mint-redeemer-file FILE | --mint-redeemer-value JSON VALUE])]
[--invalid-before SLOT]
[--invalid-hereafter SLOT]
[--certificate-file CERTIFICATEFILE
[--certificate-script-file FILE
[ --certificate-redeemer-file FILE
| --certificate-redeemer-value JSON VALUE
]]]
[--withdrawal WITHDRAWAL
[--withdrawal-script-file FILE
[ --withdrawal-redeemer-file FILE
| --withdrawal-redeemer-value JSON VALUE
]]]
[--json-metadata-no-schema | --json-metadata-detailed-schema]
[--auxiliary-script-file FILE]
[--metadata-json-file FILE | --metadata-cbor-file FILE]
[--genesis FILE | --protocol-params-file FILE]
[--update-proposal-file FILE]
--out-file FILE

Build a balanced transaction (automatically calculates fees)

Please note the order of some cmd options is crucial. If used incorrectly may produce undesired tx body. See nested [] notation above for details.
Command failed: transaction sign  Error: tx.body: tx.body: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: tx.signed: tx.signed: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

grab.sh file

cardano-cli transaction build 
--alonzo-era 
--testnet-magic 1097911063 
--change-address $(cat 02.addr) 
--tx-in a6890c2f1bbcbff5dccbd1dfeb1725af1214757c3bbdc7a4b8dcea0228ba9d18#1 
--tx-in-script-file vesting.plutus 
--tx-in-datum-file unit.json 
--tx-in-redeemer-file unit.json 
--tx-in-collateral 7691a7e471f0842deb09da58ae4d4d3c4f59e52aa3bd1eabdaadd6b940714edd#1 
--required-signer-hash edb335fdf7b7024f3ce25e556ba4cc9ea329561c16cf1a4b5353e463 
--invalid-before 1646588049 
--protocol-params-file protocol.json 
--out-file tx.body

cardano-cli transaction sign 
--tx-body-file tx.body 
--signing-key-file 01.skey 
--testnet-magic 1097911063 
--out-file tx.signed

cardano-cli transaction submit 
--testnet-magic 1097911063 
--tx-file tx.signed

```
mkValidator :: VestingDatum -> () -> ScriptContext -> Bool

mkValidator dat () ctx = traceIfFalse "beneficiary's signature 
missing" signedByBeneficiary &&
                        traceIfFalse "deadline not reached" 
 deadlineReached
   where
 info :: TxInfo
 info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx

 signedByBeneficiary :: Bool
 signedByBeneficiary = txSignedBy info $ unPaymentPubKeyHash $ 
 beneficiary dat

 deadlineReached :: Bool
 deadlineReached = contains (from $ deadline dat) $ 
 txInfoValidRange info
```

Comment: so finally found the problem and solved it change --required-signer-hash with --required-signer 02.skey that will solve the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.